# Determine eigenvalue $c$ so that the matrix is diagonalizable

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

We have a $3 \times 3$ matrix with given eigenvalues of $λ_1 = 0, λ_2 = c, λ_3 = 2$ and the eigenvectors:

$$x_1 = [1,1,2]^T, x_2 = [1,-1,0]^T, x_3 = [1,1,-1]^T$$

And the task is asking for the eigenvalue  $λ_2$, so that the matrix is diagonalizable. I've tried solving it with the $SλS^{-1}$ principle but all I've managed to get is $0 = 0$. Thanks!

Comment: What can you say if the three eigenvalues are distincts ? If two are equal, consider the associated eigen-subspace...

Answer (score 6):

Your three eigenvectors form a basis for $\Bbb R^3$ no matter what eigenvalues happen to be attached to them. Your matrix is therefore diagonalisable.